How do you create an Android AAR in .Net?
I can create an Android APK with dotnet new android, but how do I create and AAR from .Net code? Background: I have an Android service written in C# that I want to embed into a Kotlin app, including the whole .Net runtime shebang. Currently I have 2 distinct APKs, one with the service client written in Kotlin, one hosting the service, written in C#. I want to merge these two.
